# Detectar alias dentro de script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

El objetivo de mi script es borrar los alias que introduzca como parámetro. Para ello he de comprobar si el parámetro introducido es un alias o no y tengo que pedir tantos parámetros como se diga inicialmente.

```
echo "Escribe el numero de alias que quieras eliminar"
read -n 1 cantidad
echo ""
for ((i=1; i<=$cantidad; i++))
    do
    echo "Introduce un alias"
    read alias1
    if [[ $(type -t $alias1) == "alias" ]]
    then
        unalias $alias1
        echo "El alias se ha borrado correctamente"
    else
        echo "El alias no existe"
    fi
done
```

El problema de mi código es que al ejecutarlo, si introduzco un alias siempre me lo detecta como que no lo es y por lo tanto se va al else siempre.

Comment: el problema es que al ejecutar el script estás abriendo una subshell, la cual no tiene acceso a los alias que tiene la shell principal. El código está bien

Comment: @fedorqui "source <script>" en lugar de ejecutarlo como "./<script>"?

Comment: @Cuauhtli por ejemplo, sí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que ejecutar el script.sh con **source** en lugar del script únicamente

```sh
source tu_script.sh
```

Cuando corres tu script en una sh, el script se ejecuta en un nueva shell en un subproceso, por eso al momento de definir el alias, no es detectada como tal en la nueva.